# Where is the edit (existing) subtitle option in YouTube video manager?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I made some subtitles.

Where is the edit (existing) subtitle option in YouTube video manager?

[[image: Manage subtitles and closed captions[1]]

If I click on "Add new subtitles" it asks me if I want to discard existing ones:

[image: Discard published subtitles?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture, see where the blue button where it says "Add", so you know clicking there isn't what you want. Below that,  there is the green dot and it says Published: English(United Kingdom). Click there, where i've circled, then the screen changes and you can see your existing subtitles and there's an edit button.

[image]

Alternatively you could use a program or website like `subtitle-horse.com`  to make a subtitles file which seems similar to youtube's system.. and you can import that file into youtube.